# Can I use palantir for trajectory analysis in a a merged object?

Tags: single-cell

I was asked to use palantir for trajectory analysis. I have 4 samples that I have preprocessed using scanpy. Can I run the palantir analysis on the merged object or do I need to unmerge them?

Thank you

Comment: Thats a good question (but a bit brief). Palantir is [here](https://bioinformaticshome.com/tools/rna-seq/descriptions/Palantir.html#gsc.tab=0).

Comment: I have found the palantir code and I am trying to use it for my data. I was just asking if it makes sense to use it on the merged object of the 4 samples or if I should split them.